# How to add a resolution in display settings?

Tags: display, monitor, display-resolution

I have a computer using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with the ASUS Nvidia gt440 graphics card and a vga monitor that is supported with the resolution of 1280 X 800.

However, in the display options I could not find 1280 X 800 and all the other options are either causing screen to flicker or just lower resolution.

Is there a way to add a custom resolution in the display settings?

Comment: Identify your video card and what driver you are using. If xrandr does not work file a bug report.

Comment: xrandr gave an error adding new modeline. I had to change graphics cards. thanks for your reply.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `xrandr`:

The commands to be executed in order (Using 1280 x 800 as your desired resolution):

```
cvt 1280 800
xrandr --newmode "1280x800_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

The part of the line after `xrandr --newmode` is similar to the ouput you should get when using the `cvt` command, so copy the output from the "resolution_refreshRate" ("1280x800_60.00" here) point to the `+vsync` point and add it to `xrandr --newmode`.

Then:

```
xrandr --addmode LVDS1 resolution_refreshRate (don't use speechmarks)
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode resolution_refreshRate
```

If you want to make the changes permanent:

- Create a bash script, `xrandr.sh` for example, and place your xrandr commands into it:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  sudo xrandr --newmode ""1280x800_60.00"" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
  sudo xrandr --addmode LVDS1 1280x800_60.00
  xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1280x800_60.00
  ```
- Make the script executable with `chmod +x xrandr.sh`
- Search for "Startup Applications" in the dash, run it, and add the script as a startup application.

The commands will now run every time you log into your account.

**Note:** I'm using `LVDS1` as the supposed monitor name, but yours probably won't be the same. You can find your monitor name using:

```
xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }'
```