# Adding newmode with Xrandr - "800x480_60.00"

Tags: command-line, display-resolution, xrandr

I have 5-inch a 800x480 tft connected to the LVDS connector on a Portwell WADE-8020 mini-ITX embedded system board. I would like to build a XMBC/Kodi box for streming my music from my freenas PC with the tft showing what is been played, I got as fare as this...

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "800x480_60.00"  29.50  800 824 896 992  480 483 493 500 -hsync +vsync`enter code here
```

then,

```
sudo xrandr --addmode LVDS1 800x480_60.00
```

now that I get the correct resolution, I now have a black band on the top of the screen.

```
sudo xrandr --output LVDS1 --set "scaling mode"  "Full aspect"
```

However this did not solve the issue, also I know I need to amend the /bin/sh file with this from googling so I don't need to keep doing this at every boot. But I don't know how to as I'm very new to Linux.

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --newmode "800x480_60.00"  29.50  800 824 896 992  480 483 493 500 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode LVDS1 800x480_60.00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Approach 1: Using Startup Applications

You could make an [executable](https://askubuntu.com/a/484719/566421) *script* file and add it to the list of [Startup Applications](https://websetnet.com/how-to-manage-startup-applications-in-ubuntu/). [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JyO8.png) how the result of next steps looks in my system.

**1.** Create a directory where the *script* file will be contained. For example this directory could be placed into your home directory and could be named `.autorun-startup`:

```
mkdir ~/.autorun-startup
```

**2.** Create the *script* file and make it executable:

- Let's call this file `custom-screen-resolution.sh`:

  ```
  nano ~/.autorun-startup/custom-screen-resolution.sh
  ```

  <sup>In this example is used Nano text editor (where you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save the edits and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit), but you can use your favorite text editor.</sup>
- The content of the *script* `custom-screen-resolution.sh` should look as this:

  ```bsh
  #!/bin/sh
  # To calculate the modeline use: cvt 800 640 60 
  # To view the available modes and the output names use: xrandr
  # Create new mode:
  xrandr --newmode "800x480_60.00"  29.50  800 824 896 992  480 483 493 500 -hsync +vsync
  # Add the new mode to the list of modes of certain output:
  xrandr --addmode LVDS1 800x480_60.00
  # Set the new mode as current for the certain output: 
  xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 800x480_60.00
  ```
- Set executable permissions to the file `custom-screen-resolution.sh` (*or [use Nautilus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/457Gc.png)*):

  ```bsh
  chmod +x ~/.autorun-startup/custom-screen-resolution.sh
  ```

**3.** Open the application [Startup Applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFb4v.png), click on the <kbd>Add</kbd> button to add a new entry and fill the parameters values:

```bsh
Name:     Custom Screen Resolution
Command:  /home/<user>/.autorun-startup/custom-screen-resolution.sh
Comment:  Add Custom Screen Resolution
```

<kbd>Save</kbd> the entry and <kbd>Close</kbd> Startup Applications.

---

### Approach 2: Using XDG Utils

- *This approach allows you to execute the above commands during system startup system wide (for all users). For this purpose you must create [.desktop](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) file and place it into a appropriate place, to be more specific, according to the example into the directory `/etc/xdg/autostart/`. I found this approach [here](https://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/05/heres-how-to-automatically-startup-programs-for-all-users-using-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/), but there are also available and [other ways](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/0.5/ar01s02.html) how to use [XDG Utils](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-utils/) tools package.*

**1.** Create a directory where the *.desktop* file will be contained:

```bsh
sudo mkdir -p /etc/xdg/autostart
```

**2.** Create the *.desktop* file and make it executable:

- Let's call this file `custom-screen-resolution.desktop`:

  ```bsh
  sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/custom-screen-resolution.desktop
  ```
- The content of the file `custom-screen-resolution.desktop` should look as:

  ```bsh
  [Desktop Entry]
  Name=Custom Screen Resolution
  Exec=sh -c 'xrandr --newmode "800x480_60.00"  29.50  800 824 896 992  480 483 493 500 -hsync +vsync; xrandr --addmode LVDS1 800x480_60.00; xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 800x480_60.00'
  Terminal=false
  Type=Application
  Categories=Application
  ```

  Make sure `custom-screen-resolution.desktop` has [read permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) system wide.
- Set executable permissions to the file `custom-screen-resolution.desktop`. In this case, this step is optional and you need it, if you want to test your file via 'double click'.

> **Note 1:** The *.desktop* file could use the *script* created in the
>   above approach. For this purpose change the `Exec` as follow (*make sure `custom-screen-resolution.sh` has [read permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) system wide*):
>
> ```bsh
> Exec=/home/<user>/.autorun-startup/custom-screen-resolution.sh
> ```

> **Note 2:** Create the `.desktop` file within the directory `/home/<user>/.autorun-startup` and then make a [symbolic link](https://askubuntu.com/a/801191/566421) to
>   `/etc/xdg/autostart`:
>
> ```bsh
> sudo ln -s /home/<user>/.autorun-startup/custom-screen-resolution.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/
> ```

---

### Further reading

Add resolution:

- [How to set the monitor to its native resolution which is not listed in the resolutions list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19954/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-which-is-not-listed-in-the-resol)
- [How can I make xrandr customization permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent)
- [Where is the X.org config file? How do I configure X there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there)
- [How to add a resolution in display settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700222/how-to-add-a-resolution-in-display-settings)
- [How do you permanently add a resolution on a laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 for a secondary monitor connected with a VGA cable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/901348/how-do-you-permanently-add-a-resolution-on-a-laptop-with-ubuntu-14-04-for-a-seco)

Startup commands:

- [start up command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871255/start-up-command)
- [How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)
- [Differences how to run scripts at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800152/differences-how-to-run-scripts-at-startup)
- [how can i write a shell script that will run at startup and introduce a delay in the start of an application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206432/how-can-i-write-a-shell-script-that-will-run-at-startup-and-introduce-a-delay-in)
- [Adding path to PATH environment variable using bash script in /etc/environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652151/adding-path-to-path-environment-variable-using-bash-script-in-etc-environment/652169#652169)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much. I'll get back if I run into difficulty.

Comment: Another possible [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/925472/566421) - create `~/.layout.sh` and put there the `xrandr`'s statements.