# How to create new resolutions for my old notebook

Tags: display-resolution, xrandr

I looked at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution) but it fails at the second step.

I enter sudo xrandr --newmode "1280x800_60.00" ... and the Output sais:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request: BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  19
```

any Ideas how to fix my problem? thanks
[*my notebook*](https://skinflint.co.uk/wortmann-terra-mobile-home-m-2300-ic-t2390-1200771-a351028.html)

I tried to change the gamma with *sudo xrandr --output default --gamma 2:2:1* but the output just sais: xrandr: Gamma size is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that I used to keep xrandr commands permanent. First, make a file in your home folder called .layout.sh. Next, open it with your favorite text editor. Put the following line at the top: #!/bin/bash. You will need to add the .layout.sh file and run the command for all of the users who you want to have the monitor settings.

Basically, this runs the XRandR commands when you login.