# xrandr will not let me set refresh rate that monitor supports

Tags: xrandr

I have a monitor that can do the resolution 1600x1200 at 75 hertz but Ubuntu won't let me add it `xrandr -s 1600x1200 -r 75` it gives me the message `Rate 75.00 Hz not available for this size` and Ubuntu also seems to think that the monitor is 17 inches when its actually 19 inches if that helps.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding newmode with Xrandr - "800x480\_60.00"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890231/adding-newmode-with-xrandr-800x480-60-00)

Comment: no, because when I create a mode it just does nothing when I select it, it stays at the same refresh rate.

Comment: It will be worth to add all the commands, that are used in your tray...