# How do you permanently add a resolution on a laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 for a secondary monitor connected with a VGA cable?

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, laptop, lightdm, external-monitor

I found these answers, but they're old and I wonder if there are any new solutions for this.

This answer says add `xrandr` commands to `/etc/gdm/Init/Default`.

[How to set the monitor to its native resolution which is not listed in the resolutions list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19954/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-which-is-not-listed-in-the-resol)

And this answer says to edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` which I don't have on my ubuntu 14.04.

[How can I make xrandr customization permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent)

This explains how to create an xorg.conf file in case I don't have one.

[Where is the X.org config file? How do I configure X there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there)

I've also found this method of running a script on startup to add the required resolution and setting it to the relevant screen. It looks a bit hacky and I'd like to know if there's a better way.

[How to add a resolution in display settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700222/how-to-add-a-resolution-in-display-settings)

Are these relevant to 14.04 in 2017?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that I used to keep xrandr commands permanent.  First, make a file in your home folder called `.layout.sh`.  Next, open it with your favorite text editor.  Put the following line at the top: `#!/bin/bash`.  Below that, put all of the xrandr commands you want to be run on start.  Next run the following command in terminal:

```
sudo chmod +x ~/.layout.sh ; echo "DISPLAY=:0 bash ~/.layout.sh" >> .profile ; echo '' >> .profile
```

You will need to add the `.layout.sh` file and run the command for all of the users who you want to have the monitor settings.

Basically, this runs the XRandR commands when you login.

Comment: I think this method is mentioned in the last link I provided in the question.

Comment: Does it not work the way you expected?

Comment: It didn't work.
I'm now searching in the direction of drivers for on-board intel graphics cards.